# Fortran 90 - I/O passing variable as filepath

Tags: io, fortran, fortran90

This seems like it should be an easy fix, but after searching for hours I cannot find a solution.

I want to save a filepath as a character variable, then use the variable in a I/O statement.  Below is my code for reading from the file defined by "filepath".

```
character:: filepath
filepath='c:\users\chris\...\data.txt'
open(unit=1,file=filepath,status='old',action='read',form='formatted',iostat=ierror)
    if(ierror.NE.0)then
        print*,'file cannot be opened or does not exist'
        read*,
    endif
    ......
```

The program compiles (gfortran compiler using NetBeans IDE), but when I run, I get the error printed to the screen.

Note 1: When I put the filepath directly into the open function as shown below, it seems to work fine

```
open(unit=1,file='c:\\Users\\Chris\\...\\data.txt',status='old',action='read',form='formatted',iostat=ierror)
```

Note 2: I have tried all variations of forward/backward, single/double slashes in the filepath variable, so I don't think that is the problem.  When I print out "filepath" to the screen as a debugging mechanism (before the open function above), all is get back is "C".  So for some reason, it seems I am losing the rest of the filepath. (I will leave my questions regarding what slash method is appropriate until I research it more)

I appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've declared `filepath` to be a character variable of length 1. Change the declaration to something like `character(80):: filepath` (use a length long enough to contain the entire path).

Comment: Sure enough.  Rookie Fortran mistake :)  Thanks for the quick response.